# Android LiveData - Object value is not updated

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I use Kotlin Flow and LiveData to fetch objects from room database. I want to know that the value of the object in the database has changed. I did the following;

**UserDao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:userId")
fun getUserById(userId: String?) : Flow<User>
```

**UserRepository**

```
fun getUserById(userId: String?) : Flow<User> = userDao.getUserById(userId);
```

**ViewModel**

```
val userId = MutableStateFlow<String>("")

val user : LiveData<User> = userId.flatMapLatest { id ->
    userRepository.getUserById(id)
}.asLiveData()
```

There is no problem while fetching the data but when I change the user's name, the "user.name" value is not updated.

Note: Changing in database, checked.

I update the name as follows:

```
@Query("UPDATE user SET name = :name WHERE id = :userId")
suspend fun updateName(name: String, userId: String)
```

Comment: can you provide the code for updating the name?

Comment: @SamiShorman Can you check my update?

Comment: and how u call updateName() from ui, and why u don't use @Update annotation in room and pass the new user object to the function , i will submit as answer maybe it will help.

Comment: @MuratAKSU do you ping `userId` object while updating the database. Otherwise I don't think `upstream` will be triggered and deliver data to `downstream`. I didn't understand the flow here.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this to achieve what you want:

in Doa:

```
@Update
suspend fun updateUser(user:User)
```

and in ui:

```
user.name = newName
updateUser(user)
```

I know that's not the way u want, but it can give you same behavior, thank you.